# Adding various content type within Table View Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am new to IOS programming and will need some direction here.
I am trying to create a tableview with each rows having a image and some text.

I am able to take a TableViewController and programmatically was able to add basic text and rows. But can you please tell me how should i add more complex content. Trying to achieve something like this using program.

[image]

My current code looks like this in my TableViewController and its able to print a text message on each row.

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    var mycell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("frontcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    mycell.textLabel.text = "Just a generic message"

    return mycell
}
```

There is a

```
mycell.contentView
```

which takes in UIView. But how does it works? How should this object be created?

Appreciate your help.

------Update -----
Thanks to Suryakant for helping out. Answer below for his step by step how to do. Any one who needs the source code can use this. http://pastebin.com/ZfNqK4tW

Comment: This might help you according to your requirement
*http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you can achieve it by default `UITableViewCell` also, as `@meda` mention in his answer,
but it seems, you want different `UIImageView` size and 2 `UILabels` with different font size or may be some more controls there. For Achieving that you need to customize `UITableViewCell` and you can do that by subclassing `UITableViewCell` class.

1. Create a class by subclassing UITableViewCell.

   e.g. your subclass say MyCell look like —

[image]

2.Go to storyboard and select **prototypeCell** and select `Identity inspector`, in Class type your custom class name (e.g MyCell )in place of `UITableViewCell`.
drag-n-drop all the controls you need and link with their `IBOutlets` (From MyCell to prototypeCell).

This goes as below..

[image]

3.Now goto `Attributes Selector` and give some `Identifier` to your `MyCell`, you can give any string you want.

[image]

4.Goto the class where you implemented UITableView delegates  and update your cellForIndexPath as bellow

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
 NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let kCellIdentifier:String  = "cell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as MyCell!
    if cell == nil {
        // register Custom UITableView Class to UITableView
        tableView.registerClass(MyCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
        cell = MyCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
    }
    if var label = cell.cellMyCity{
        label.text = cityList[indexPath.row]
    }
    if var label = cell.cellMyCountry{
        label.text = countryList[indexPath.row]
    }
    if var imageView = cell.imageView{
        imageView.image = UIImage(named :"img.png")
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

For reference you can see [example code here](https://github.com/suryakants/TableViewOperationInSwift).

Comment: Thanks Suryakant. Exactly what i was looking for. Do you know why the output looks broken. Seems like its printing all on the same place. Here is a screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/ziyonqrubr60h4r/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-17%20at%206.41.24%20PM.png

Comment: And i modified the controller code a bit and here is the whole code for everyone's reference http://pastebin.com/ZfNqK4tW

Comment: Might be some beta xcode 6 issue. I just reduced the number of rows to 1, compiled and then increased the rows and its working fine. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: labels looks stretched, try to increase Cell height.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and then assign values to the property of your cell

```
mycell.textLabel.text = "Just a generic message"
mycell.detailTextLabel.text = "Just a detail message"
mycell.imageView.text = myImage
```

And for that you would use only one prototype Cell no need to duplicate them.